# How to resolve SQL table with prefix in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on PhpStorm to develop my Prestashop websites and I can't resolve this issue. I work on localhost and successfully connected PhpStorm to my MySQL Server.

Now PhpStorm throws warnings like "unable to resolve table '${_DB_PREFIX_}cms'". Prestashop uses prefixes for table names and it seems PhpStorm can't resolve those tables with prefixes.

Is there a workaround for this ?

Here is a code exemple from Prestashop-1.6 sources :

```
$sql = 'SELECT c.`id_cms`, cl.`meta_title`, cl.`link_rewrite`
    FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cms` c
    INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cms_shop` cs
    ON (c.`id_cms` = cs.`id_cms`)
    INNER JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cms_lang` cl
    ON (c.`id_cms` = cl.`id_cms`)
    WHERE c.`id_cms_category` = '.(int)$id_cms_category.'
    AND cs.`id_shop` = '.(int)$id_shop.'
    AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$id_lang.
    $where_shop.'
    AND c.`active` = 1
    ORDER BY `position`';
```

[image: Error in PhpStorm for Mysql tables with prefixes]

Comment: Not currently possible -- watch https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26986 (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: Thank you, I've vote for this issue, I hope it will be corrected soon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Edit:** At time of writing (2016) there was no solution to this issue. But since 2018, as mentioned in [Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51730952/1539115), you can now [use constants in SQL queries](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26986).

---

Actually there is no way to handle that. But you may disable inspection for such warning.

1. Open `File` > `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inspections`
2. Expand `SQL`
3. Uncheck `Unresolved reference`

Comment: So we can't have inspection to check for good tables, columns names ? That's a little bit frustrating... Thanks for this quick answer.

Comment: You should open a ticket on their issue tracker. They are really productive. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: Turning off the error doesn't fix the problem. After you've loaded the correct schema you can then tell PhpStorm what external variables to ignore or listen to which will resolve both issues.

Comment: Christian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51730952/3102305) actually solves it!

Answer (score 11):

The reason why this isn't work is because you are most likely only loading one schema, you need to load the `information_schema.*`

To do this, go to the database tab in the top right and where you have added your MySQL database right click and select properties.

Now you'll have a screen called `Data Sources and Drivers`, it should open on a tab called `General`, click the third tab called `Schemas` and and add `information_schema.*` to this list of loaded Schemas.

Click apply and okay and then PhpStorm will now know your database structure and then be intelligently able to work with you, therefor removing all the errors.

Comment: Still no change, Phpstorm can't resolve `"._DB_PREFIX_."` in my queries.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** As [mentioned here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26986), this has been fixed in PhpStorm 2018.2, but *only for constants*.

---

I have a solution that doesn't involve throwing your IDE away. :)
However, a word of caution: it's an ugly hack™ that comes without guarantees.

1. Assuming you already have a connection to the db in PhpStorm, generate the ddl for the desired db (Right Click on the connection -> SQL Scripts -> Generate DDL to Clipboard):

   [image: Imgur]
2. Paste the content into some sql file somewhere inside your project. You should probably gitignore this file.
3. Replace all the tables' prefix in this ddl file with the one from your code. Use the PhpStorm typehint as a guideline. For example `'._DB_PREFIX_.'cms` would become `${_DB_PREFIX_}cms`:

   [image: Imgur]

   Note that you may have to use backticks to avoid breaking sql syntax due to curly brackets.
4. Add the ddl to your phpstorm project:

   [image: Imgur]
5. Everything should now work:

   [image: Imgur]

Comment: Thank you @Christian, this is awesome! I had difficulties with the fact that you gave the example for the ddl code to be `${_DB_PREFIX_}cms` while your screenshot showed `${{$this->tablePrefix}}cms` (with he double braces). None of those worked for me in PhpStorm 2020.3. However, the syntax that worked was to use `%name` instead of `${_DB_PREFIX_}` or `${{$this->tablePrefix}}`. So I've requested an edit to your answer that would add that information.

Answer (score 2):

Add this comment above the **$sql** query.
/** @noinspection SqlResolve */

This will suppress the warning only for this statement.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, this is now supported:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2021.1/ide-advanced-metadata.html#set-up-dynamic-prefixes-for-table-names-in-sql-language-injections

.phpstorm.meta.php

```
<?php

namespace PHPSTORM_META {
override(
// Virtual function to indicate that all SQL
// injections will have the following replacement rules.
sql_injection_subst(),
map([
'{' => "", // all `{` in injected SQL strings will be replaced with a prefix
'}' => '',        // all `}` will be replaced with an empty string
]));
}
```